# Update application.yml in Spring

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-cloud-config, application.properties

I have a tiny spring-boot app. I want to be able to update beans configuration via http endpoint. Going to do this via beans setters. I mean update injected via `@Value` or `@ConfigurationProperties` fields via java code. Nothing special here.

But I want to store updated properties back to application.yml to be able to load them on next startup. This could be done via some custom code, but in general the task sounds like something that already should exist.

Is anybody did it? Update/store app config at runtime. I saw `spring-could-config` but it a bit overengineering for me having git repo and config server.

Thanks for any response!

Comment: application.yml is the wrong place for this. Use some sorts of database instead (which a config server is basically)

Comment: @luk2302, yep, you are right. I thought about key-value storage, but it's a bit overhead for my app. I'm not gonna to scale it somehow for now.